# AndroidSchedulers.mainThread stopped working in patch rxAndoidBle 1.4

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

**Before the 1.4 update you could just write:**

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

and import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers; but now I can not make this work.

Is this moved / removed or does it exist another implementation now to get similar effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library no longer relies on [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid).

Make sure that you've put `compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:XXX'` in your build.gradle, if you want to use it's classes in your code.

It's not a good pracitse to rely on tranitive dependencies, you should declare them on your own.